# How to bring any character [ ex ; ] to a line before in notepad++ for all the sequence

Tags: notepad++

I have some statements like this in notepad ++

```
INSERT INTO ZZZZZZZ (A,B,C,D)
VALUES (1,2,3,4)
;
```

I need to put the semicolon after the end of line 2 for all the occurrences.
Desired output :

```
INSERT INTO ZZZZZZZ (A,B,C,D)
VALUES (1,2,3,4);
```

How to do that in notepad++

Comment: Maybe just replace `\R+;` with `;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    $\R;
Replace: ;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to move the semicolon from the line below to the position after the closing bracket, simply mark the closing bracket and the semicolon in the next row, then click CTRL+H to replace it and type ); in the second line as the string to replace the first string with.